# How to Use f2py module in python

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Just having a bit of trouble with using f2py. I have compiled to following code into a .so file just fine, and it imports into my python code just fine, but I am just wondering how do I then use it. I know there is a command *doc* but it jus says that this module has no attribute called "*doc*"

Fortran Code:

```
subroutine Test
implicit none
real, dimension(3600000) :: Alpha,Sigma
open(10, file='Alpha.txt')
read(10, *) Alpha
Sigma = (87.6*2)/((87.6*(sin(Alpha))**2)+(2*cos(Alpha)**2))
end subroutine
```

Python Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import Sigma

print(Sigma._doc_)
```

Error:

```
File "/home/tom/Desktop/f2py/Plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(Sigma._doc_)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_doc_'
```

Do I have to somehow enter the doc attribute into the original fortran code? If so how would I go about that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the doc? Why do you think there should be any doc present? Were you able to run the test subroutine?

Comment: You have to use the doc to find out how the functions are stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html), it looks like you need to call the print on `module.subroutine.__doc__`.

If I save your file to `test1.f90`, then compile it

```
f2py -c test1.f90 -m test1
```

And then query the doc string.

```
~$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:35:40) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20171224] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import test1
>>> print(test1.test.__doc__)
test()

Wrapper for ``test``.


>>>
```

Which looks fine to me since you have no arguments going to `Test`.